# Windows API - Clipboard - GlobalLock - use or not to use?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, global-variables, clipboard

I've seen practise that if you are going to get contents from the Windows clipboard by `GetClipboardData()`, the `GlobalLock()` function is called on handle returned by `GetClipboardData()` first - before retrieving the data (e.g.convert&store).

However I found out that (at least in C++11) I can get the same data without the locking...

So there are 3 sub questions...

1. How is this possible?
2. Is it safe in one-thread app ran only "single"?
3. Is it safe in one-thread app ran simultaneously multiple times?

...resulting in one BIG question - use or not to use `GlobalLock()` **&& when?**

*PS: Of course after each potencial `GlobalLock()` you should call `GlobalUnlock()`*

This is simplyfied part where I retrieve the data:

```
HANDLE clipboardHandle;
string clipboardContents = "";
clipboardHandle = GetClipboardData( CF_OEMTEXT );
clipboardContents = (string)static_cast<char*>( clipboardHandle );
cout << "Clipboard data:" << clipboardContents; //prints out fine
```

Comment: The value returned from `GlobalLock` has been the same value passed to it since 32-bit Windows. Calling `GlobalLock` has nothing to do with multithreading either - it's a remnant of 16-bit Windows, which never implemented preemptive multithreading. Should you still call `GlobalLock` even though it doesn't do anything today? Yes! Technical background is outlined at [A history of GlobalLock, part 3: Transitioning to Win32](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/08/253891.aspx).

Comment: The [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709.aspx) is a global resource: All applications running in the same desktop have access to the same Clipboard. The reason for calling `GlobalLock` is outlined in the article I posted above: Calling [GlobalFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366577.aspx) will return wrong information if you don't. And since the clipboard is a global resource, you have to not break working code inside other applications.

Comment: @IInspectable Aren't other apps supposed to NOT to count on what other apps do? :)

Comment: @IInspectable BTW: can I GlobalLock it, then read it as is ( `cb = static_cast<char*>(CBH);` and then GlobalUnlock it ? (I mean like 3 lines - do you get me?)

Comment: Why would you want to go against the documentation and skip the call to `GlobalLock`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you mean this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx where there is ONLY comment about it ?

Answer (score 6):

`GlobalAlloc` can return two different things depending on how it is called.

`GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, n)` returns a pointer to an immobile lump of memory.  `GlobalLock` is superfluous: it will return the same value.

`GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, n)` returns a handle, which is not a pointer to the data.  You need to call `GlobalLock` to convert it to a pointer, and you'll get a different value back.

If you don't know which way the memory was allocated call `GlobalLock`.

Comment: The `SetClipboardData()` documentation specifically states that the memory object MUST be allocated with `GMEM_MOVABLE`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is true, yet when you read clipboard data from another process the system-allocated memory returned by `GetClipboardData` is fixed, not moveable!  (For `CF_TEXT` anyway, I haven't checked that this is consistent across all formats.)

Comment: Keep in mind that `GetClipboardData()` can return synthesized data. If the clipboard does not contain `CF_TEXT` specifically, but does contain something that can be converted to `CF_TEXT`, the clipboard will do that conversion when you request `CF_TEXT`. So it is possible that a fixed global object is be created in that situation while the original global object is still movable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It doesn't matter if the clipboard format is synthesised or not; the memory handle you receive in your process will have been created by the system.